# Exception handling in python Counting the number of characters in a string

Tags: python

This is my code.

```
def word_count(my_string):
    count=1
    if type(my_string) == str:
        try:
            for eachCharacter in my_string:
                if eachCharacter==' ':
                    count+=1
            return count
        except:
            return "Not a string"
```

i have to get output as:

```
Word Count: 4
Word Count: 1
Word Count: 7
Word Count: Not a string
Word Count: Not a string
Word Count: Not a string
```

but i'm getting:

```
Word Count: 4
Word Count: 1
Word Count: 7
Word Count: None
Word Count: None
Word Count: None
```

Can anyone help me in finding this error

Comment: Please put your code inside code sampes like `this`.

Comment: @Tharshika Elangovan, please edit your question and add there what inputs you are using so that we can check on them.

Comment: Either put if inside try and "Not a string" in else statement. Or raise TypeError inside if with the current code. What are you trying to do here? How does the input look like?

Comment: It would be good if you could include the input that leads to the result you show, although it's clear to me that you are calling your function three times with a string as a parameter and then three times with something that is not a string (including, possibly, None).  It's possible to answer your question, as I did, without knowing anything more than that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the case where the input is not a string:

```
def word_count(my_string):
    count=1
    if type(my_string) == str:
        for eachCharacter in my_string:
            if eachCharacter==' ':
                count+=1
        return count
    return "Not a string"
```

As you have it now, your function doesn't explicitly return anything, and therefore returns `None`, if the passed in object is not a string.  Also, the try/except does you no good since the code inside the `try` will never throw an exception.